# How Can I scrape source URL of online streaming video?

Tags: javascript, html, curl, web-scraping, video-streaming

I have been struggling to get the source URL of this video stream [url](https://nflstream.io/nfl-network-live/stream-1)

I see it's using the m3u8 format file via chrome developer tools but I couldn't find the complete link.
But is there any way I can scrape it and run that stream externally via m3u8 player ?? ANy help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

They're sending chunks of data and not entire video file so if you're trying to scrape it it's not possible. Prolly multiple requests but I still have my doubts

Comment: yea, I figured it out too, is there a way to find request API ? they keep calling  this link https://e8.dotice.me/plyvivo/klIizm6uM2g1U57fHDJC/chunklist.m3u8 in chunk. if I call it through external m3u8 player nothing plays

Comment: I doubt they might be calling that same link. Also they might have cors enabled so I don't think so even if they're it's of any use